# Adicionar QRCode em PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, qrcode

Estou gerando um PDF com respostas de um formulário usando [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf), o PDF gera corretamente, porém fui adicionar um QRCode para ser usado como controle e validação deles, porém não consigo encontrar nada sobre como fazer esta adição, alguém tem uma dica de onde procurar, material para leitura, qualquer coisa?

Obrigado e desculpem se este tipo de pergunta não for válida

Comment: Você está gerando o PDF a partir do HTML?

Comment: @richellyitalo já consegui resolver sozinho, usei a [VanillaQR](https://www.cssscript.com/canvas-based-qr-code-generator-pure-javascript-vanillaqr-js/) e gerou corretamente, obrigado